# uWSGI set configuration depending on environment variable value

Tags: uwsgi

I have an environment variable DEBUG. Its value either could be true or false. I want to set few configurations based on its value.

```
[uwsgi]
if-opt = $(DEBUG)=true 
print = Inside if condition
endif =
```

Print statement is not executing. DEBUG is setup in the kubernetes deployment

```
- name: DEBUG
  value: "true"
```

Comment: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html?highlight=environment#environment-variables

Comment: thanks @niko for sharing. I checked that but not able to find what is the issue with my if-opt statement?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is `if-opt` checks if a given **uWSGI option** is set, it does not inspect environment variables.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but one workaround would be to define a custom option, load the environment variable into it, and then use `if-opt`:

```
declare-option = my-debug=false

if-env = DEBUG
my-debug = %(_)
endif =

if-opt = my-debug=true
print = Inside if condition
endif =
```

If instead of using true/false values you could use empty string / non-empty string values, this could be much simpler:

```
if-env = DEBUG
print = Inside if condition
endif =
```